# Sequencial firebase queries in swiftui. First query returns userIDs the second fetches user profiles for those UIDs. Best approach?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

Am looking to use the latest codable features of firebase in order to

1. run a query against firebase collection to return a map of user identifiers and then,
2. use the resulting map to drive a second query against firebase to return a map full of the user profile documents for those identities.

My biggest concern is in handling the async nature of the first query, i.e. how to wait for it to return before issuing the second query.

Notice the class below and two functions.  The two functions need to be called in sequence and the async nature of the calls is somewhat new to me.  During class init(), I instantiate the first function call to load a set of userIDs. Once I have those userIDs loaded, I want to call the 2nd function to fetch the corresponding user profiles.

```
 class PlayerRepository: ObservableObject {
    
    private let store = Firestore.firestore()
    private let path:       String = "Players"
    private let friendPath: String = "MyFriends"
    @Published var players:   [UserProfile] = []
    @Published var friendIDs: [Friends] = []

    var userId = ""
    
    private let authenticationService = AuthenticationService()
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    init() {
        authenticationService.$user
            .compactMap { user in
                user?.uid
            }
            .assign(to: \.userId, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        authenticationService.$user
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                self?.getFriendIDs( )

            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    func getFriendIDs( ) {
        
        store.collection(friendPath)
           // the following line works great
            .whereField("myID", isEqualTo:  userId)
            .addSnapshotListener { [self] querySnapshot, error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error getting > Players: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                self.friendIDs = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap { document in
                    try? document.data(as: Friends.self)
                } ?? []
                

                // the following is firing before the friendIDs map is loaded so I get nothing back.
                if (self.friendIDs.count > 0) {
                    authenticationService.$user
                        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                        .sink { [weak self] _ in
                            self?.get( )

                        }
                        .store(in: &cancellables)
                   // print(self.friendIDs[0].myFriends)
                }

                
                print("userid im searching for is: \(self.userId) total found: \(self.friendIDs.count)")
            }

    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    func get( ) {
        
        store.collection(path)
           // the following line works fine
            .whereField(FieldPath.documentID(), in: self.friendIDs[0].myFriends)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error getting > Players: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                self.players = querySnapshot?.documents.compactMap { document in
                    
                    try? document.data(as: UserProfile.self)
                } ?? []
                
                // the following seems to only begin once the array is full - but then it prints the 38 count 38 times as though this print is in a loop
                //self.getFriendIDs()
                print(self.players.count)

            }

    }
```

Any pointers on approach?  I've been unable to find examples like this.

Phil

Comment: There are examples of how to query (with codable) in the documentation but more importantly, what have you tried? Can you include you code so we can take a look? Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure thing, thanks, Jay.  I'll post the code shortly.